# Purpose of Cap to Ground in this Circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, remote-control

I came across this circuit and I am curious about the reason for C2 being where it is. If I am analyzing the circuit correctly, this is effectively just C1 and C2 in parallel. What is the benefit of doing it this way as opposed to just a larger cap for c1? Something with bouncing of the switch perhaps? Any sage wisdom would be greatly appreciated (note that the actual passive values aren't important here; I just knocked this together to make it easier to ask the question).

[image]

EDIT: After reading a few answers, I want to post the whole circuit. What I am extracting is the circuit for EN, and SW2 here.

The components I brought together in that simplified diagram have arrows to them. Note I omitted the transistors Q1 and Q2, since I didn't think it changed my core question, but perhaps I am wrong here. So if that's the case, my question still is, what is the purpose of that capacitor? In the full schematic it is C14.

[image]

Comment: The circuit doesn't appear to do anything useful so, without an explanation of what the circuit is intended to do, there's nothing to add. It might be that the circuit is intended to fuse the contacts of S2 when it is pressed. In that case, it needs to be there if the distance to C1 is large.

Comment: Where did you come across this circuit? Are you sure there was no mistake when reading it?

Comment: maybe somebody drew the diagram without thinking ... maybe copy & paste ... or just thinking in "circuit blocks" instead of individual components

Comment: @Andyaka  I updated my post to include the circuit I am looking at.

Comment: Then it's a flaky design unless it is intended to weld shut the contacts.

Comment: @Andyaka is this taking into account the entire design I posted?

Comment: May I ask which design it is? Or in fact, when you quote a picture, you must provide the original source by whom it is too, just like in real life.

Comment: @Justme -- it's just the reference design for the devkitc, available from https://www.espressif.com/en/support/download/documents/development-board -- I don't know who the author is.

Comment: @jsinglet Mentioning that is the Espressif reference design for some product is enough in my opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that the two capacitors both being drawn and mounted at the same time is an error, which may be corrected by removing it in the bill of materials (BOM) - see how the capacitor on the other button is marked green with (NC) which may mean it should be left out.

However, this is not unheard of, mistakes happen, like when you already have drawn the RC circuit for the pin, and then do the debouncing cap at the button.

It may also be that the capacitor has been removed from the wrong button, as the other button has now two caps, and the other one has none.

Suffice to say, there may not be a huge purpose for the schematic to be like it is. Having two debounce caps on one button is not the biggest mistake left on the board.

Answer (score 2):

Having C2 there is identical to just making C1 = 2uF. The schematic creator doesn't know what they are doing and seems to think C2 is somehow different than C1 and has drawn it accordingly.

The only reason I can think of is if they are trying to use it as a snubber to suppress arcing across the button and so wire a capacitor directly across the button but that could cause problems without a series resistance. But that would depend on physical wiring given the lack of inductance and high resistance of the circuit it doesn't make much sense.